# How to set read for different characters in bash-shell?

Tags: bash

How to set read for different characters?  Does anyone know a solution?

```
while true
do
    read -sn3 KEY

        case "$KEY" in
             $'\x1b[A') echo "press arrow up";;   # OK
             $'\x1b[B') echo "press arrow down";; # OK
             $'\x1b[15~') echo "press key F5";;   # Problem !!!
        esac
done
```

Thank you

Comment: what do you expect from this code? what do you actually get?

Comment: jolivier: dump text keystrokes by

Comment: If F5 is generating all of `$'\x1b[15~'` -- five characters -- then naturally your code won't work, because you've told `read` to read only the first three characters.

Comment: ruakh: yes I know, but I do not know how to fix it, thank you

Answer (score 4):

It's a little overkill!

So I would first enjoin you to take a look at `dialog`, `whiptail` and other `curses` wrapper for shell.

But at all this could make the job. (I the hope you'll never put them on production stage ;-)

```
$ char=""; while [ ! "$char" ] ;do
    char="$(
        (
            stty -echo raw
            dd bs=1 if=/dev/tty of=/dev/fd/4 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
            sleep .1
            kill $! 2>/dev/null
            stty sane
        ) 4>&1 >/dev/null
    )"
    done
$ echo -n "$char" | od -A n -t c
 033   [   2   4   ~
```

**UPDATED** (again)

... assuming you will not press two different key in less than 0.1 second.
(This could not be true even, but in case on dialog menu, this may be...)

From there:

```
readKey() {
    local char
    while [ ! "$char" ] ;do
        char="$(
            (
                stty -echo raw
                dd bs=1 if=/dev/tty of=/dev/fd/4 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
                sleep .1
                kill $! 2>/dev/null
                stty sane
            ) 4>&1 >/dev/null
        )"
      done
    printf -v ${1:-REPLY} "$char"
}
str=""
while [ "$str" != "exit" ] ;do
    readKey KEY
    str+="$KEY"
    [ ${#str} -gt 4 ] && str="${str:${#str}-4}"
    case "$KEY" in
         $'\x1b[A') echo "press arrow up";;   # OK
         $'\x1b[B') echo "press arrow down";; # OK
         $'\x1b[15~') echo "press key F5";;   # Ok, for me.
         * ) echo "pressed: '$(echo -n "$KEY"| od -A n -t c)'" ;;
    esac
done
```

Than hit some keys...

```
press key F5
press arrow up
press arrow down
pressed: ' 033   [   F'
pressed: ' 033   [   6   ~'
pressed: ' 033   [   3   ~'
pressed: '   q'
pressed: '   e'
pressed: '   x'
pressed: '   i'
pressed: '   t'
```

Hit *`e x i t`* for ending the loop.

Comment: Your solution is not for me:-( I need a solution to my original question

Comment: @Charlie: Is that not a response to your original question?

Comment: :-( And not just to find out how many characters the variable $KEY?
<pre><code>
if [[ ${#KEY} == 5 ]]; then read -sn5 KEY; else read -sn3 KEY; fi
</code></pre>

Comment: How do you wanna do that!? You coud not know the length of the key **before** the key is pressed!